# If $f^2=id_V$ then f is diagonizable

Tags: linear-algebra

I am trying to prove the following statement, which wasn't proven in my course but seems really important,

> Let $f \in End(V)$, if $f^2=id_V \Rightarrow f$  is  diagonizable. (the characteristic of the field is not 2)

It seems intuitive to me, but I can't find a way to prove it, the only thing I noticed has to be true is that $f\restriction_{Imf} = id_V$ has to hold, pls help

Comment: *Hint.* There is a degree-$2$ polynomial with simple roots that cancels $f$ (assuming the characteristic is not $2$).

Comment: I did not say that $f=\pm\mathrm{Id}$…

Comment: A rephrasing of what I said: $V=\ker(f-\mathrm{Id})\oplus\ker(f+\mathrm{Id})$. Can you show that?

Comment: I will reflect on your answer, I was answering to another comment which I think has been deleted. Thanks a lot for your tip

Comment: The statement is false in a field of characteristic $2$.

Comment: @user8675309 idempotence, buddy, idempotence :)

Comment: @AlvinL ... good catch.  it seems autocorrect strikes again

Answer (score 3):

From $f^2 - \mathrm{id} = 0$ conclude its minimal polynomial divides $x^2-1$. If the characteristic is not two, then the minimal polynomial cannot have repeated roots.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\mathcal{B}$ be a basis of the vector space $V$ and $A=\mathcal{M}(f,\mathcal{B},\mathcal{B})$. Then $A^2=\mathcal{M}(f^2,\mathcal{B},\mathcal{B})= I_n$. So we conclude that the minimal polynomial $q$ divides $r(x)=x^2-1=(x+1)(x-1)$. From this we have tree options $q(x)=x+1, \; q(x)=x-1,$ or $q(x)=r(x)$. Either way, the minimal polynomial is of the form,

\begin{equation*}
q(x)=(x-\lambda_1)(x-\lambda_2) \cdots (x-\lambda_n)
\end{equation*}
and from another theorem (see proof below) we have $A$ is diagonizable and so is $f$.

**Theorem:** An endomorphism $f$ of a vector space $V$, over $\mathbb{K}$, with $\text{dim}(V) \geq 1$, is diagonizable if and only if it's minimal polynomial is of the form,
\begin{equation*}
q(x)=(x-\lambda_1)(x-\lambda_2) \cdots (x-\lambda_n)
\end{equation*}
where, $\lambda_1,\lambda_2 \dots \lambda_n$ are eigenvalues of $f$.

**Proof**

$(\Rightarrow)$
If $f$ is diagonizable then there exists a basis $\mathcal{B}$ formed by eigenvalues.

Let $\lambda_1,\lambda_2 \dots \lambda_n$, be distinct eigenvalues of $f$. Then we have  $\lambda_1,\lambda_2 \dots \lambda_n$ are roots of the minimal polynomial. So we have that $q(x)=(x-\lambda_1)(x-\lambda_2) \cdots (x-\lambda_n)$ divides de minimal polynomial of $f$, from this we conclude that the degree of the minimal polynomial is greater or equal to $n$.

Let $u$ be a vector of the basis $\mathcal{B}$. Then $u$ is an eigenvalue of $f$ associated with $\lambda_j, j \in \{1,...,n\}$, so we have,
\begin{equation*}
q(x)=(x-\lambda_1)\cdots(x-\lambda_{j-1})(x-\lambda_{j+1})\cdots(x-\lambda_n)(x-\lambda_j)
\end{equation*}

then,
\begin{equation*}
(q(f))(u)=((f-\lambda_1 id_V) \circ \dots \circ (f-\lambda_{j-1}id_V) \circ (f-\lambda_{j+1}id_V)\circ \dots \circ (f-\lambda_n id_V)\circ(f-\lambda_{j}id_V))(u)
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
=((f-\lambda_1 id_V) \circ \dots \circ (f-\lambda_{j-1}id_V) \circ (f-\lambda_{j+1}id_V)\circ \dots \circ (f-\lambda_n id_V)(f(u)-\lambda_j u)
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
=((f-\lambda_1 id_V) \circ \dots \circ (f-\lambda_{j-1}id_V) \circ (f-\lambda_{j+1}id_V)\circ \dots \circ (f-\lambda_n id_V)(0_V)=0_V
\end{equation*}

Then, the image of any vector of the basis $\mathcal{B}$ by the endomorphism $q(f)$ is $0_V$.

Hence, $q(f)$ it's the null endomorphism, so the degree of the minimal polynomial is less or equal to $n$, so it's degree is $n$ (from the beginning of the proof). Since $q$ has degree $n$, and it's monic , $q$ is in fact the minimal polynomial of $f$.

$(\Leftarrow)$

We're going to prove this by induction in the dimension of $V$.

Suppose now that $V$ is a vector space over $\mathbb{K}, \text{dim}(V)=1$ and $f$ an endomorphism of $V$. Then it's characteristic polynomial has degree $1$, and it's of the form $(x-\lambda), \lambda \in \mathbb{K}$. Then the matrix of $f$ in any basis is $1 \times 1$, so it's diagonal. Then $f$ is diagonizable.

Now for a general case suppose, $\text{dim}(V)=n>1$. Also, suppose, that all endomorphisms of a vector space $E$, with $1 \leq \text{dim}(E)=m \leq n$, with the minimal polynomial of the form previously assumed are diagonizable (hypothesis).

Assume now $f$ an endomorphism of $V$ with minimal polynomial $q(x)=(x-\lambda_1)(x-\lambda_2) \cdots (x-\lambda_n)$,$\lambda_1,\lambda_2 \dots \lambda_n$, distinct eigenvalues of $f$.

If $n=1$, then the minimal polynomial is $(x-\lambda_1)$ and so $f-\lambda_1 id_V$ is the null endomorphism and $f$ is diagonizable.

If $n>1$, consider $f-\lambda_n id_V$ and $W= \text{Im}(f-\lambda_n id_V)$, we know from another theorem that $0< \text{dim}(W)<n$, so let's consider $f_W: W \to W$, the restriction of $f$ to $W$, and we have that the minimal polynomial of $f_W$ divides $(x-\lambda_1) \cdots (x-\lambda_{n-1})$ and that the union of a basis of $W$ with a basis of $V_{\lambda_n}$, its a basis of $V$. So from our hypothesis $f_W$ is diagonizable. Then exists a basis of $W$ formed by eigenvectors of $f_W$. The union of all this basis with a basis of $V_{\lambda_n}$ makes a basis of $V$. Since eigenvectors of $f_W$ are eigenvectors of $f$, we have basis of $V$ formed by eigenvalues, so $f$ is diagonizable.

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for giving such a complete answer. I am trying to understand everything, but I wanted to ask something. In my course we stated the theorem in the following way: f is diagonizable iff the two following hold a) every root of P(lambda) is in K b) the algebraic multiplicity of the eigenvalue as the root of P(lambda) and the geometric multiplicity (the dimension of the associated eigenspace) are equal. Can you confirm these two theorems are equivalent?

Comment: Hello, I don't understand the first claim you do since every root of the characteristic polynomial is always in K, if you consider K=R or K=C. Regarding to the second claim yes it is true for any eigenvalue, its algebraic multiplicty must equal the geometric multiplicity, so f is diagonizable.
I'll try to summarize every result I know about matrix/endomorphism in the coment below.

Comment: f/A is diagonizable iif there exists a basis of the vector space V forme by eigenvectors.
f/A is diagonizable iif the sum of the geometric multiplicities of all eigenvectors equals the dimension of the vector space.
f/A is diagonizable iif for any eigenvector it's geometric multiplicity equals the algebraic one.
f/A is diagonizable iif it's minimal polynomial has no repeated roots (Theorem stated and proved above).
Hope this helps.